# Modifying Content Manager Installation unattended

Tags: web8.5, content-manager, translation-manager, installation

We have created Power shell scripts to Install SDL Web 8.5 CMS in unattended mode. Now we need to Install Translation Manager Feature, We can add that using "TranslationManager_SelectedFeatures" and Set that attribute to All.
How to pass action parameter as "Modify" so that only that feature will be installed without overriding current installed feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enabling `$Params.Add("TranslationManager_SelectedFeatures", '(All)')` appended to existing configured parameters and by providing below parameters in script

```
$Params.Add("TM_TS_LIST","")              
$Params.Add("TM_TMS_ADDRESS","")                                                
$Params.Add("TM_TMS_PORT","")                                                    
$Params.Add("TM_DB_SERVER","(local)")                              
$Params.Add("TM_DB_NAME","Tridion_TranslationManager")   
$Params.Add("TM_DB_USER","TMUser")                               
$Params.Add("TM_DB_PASSWORD","")
```

and while installing append -modify as shown below

```
SDLWeb85CM.exe -s -modify
```

Its installed Translation Manager alone without effecting other installed features.